# Is it possible to user current_user with as_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models: user, likes and posts. I am using as_json and want to see if user has liked a post. In `post.rb` when I do `self.likes` it shows all likes for that post; however, I want to show only one like(if it exists) from current user only. `self.likes.user` doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to achieve that with as_json?

Comment: You really should show some code (your models with their association definitions would be a good starting point). Otherwise, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: Models do not have any information about a `current_user` because a current user is a concept in the context of a single request and therefore a controller domain. If you want to use the current user in a model method then you have to pass it from the controller to the model. You are a bit vague about what you try to achieve and without having seen your actual code (especially the associations) the question is hard to answer. Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with

```
post.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

To limit result to one **like**

```
post.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(1)
```

**Note** : make sure **current_user** object available when accessing it in MODEL. If it's not available pass it as method argument.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have used ```self.likes.where(:user_id => self.user)```